# Deleting Rows in .xls using python Script

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python But what I want to do as of now is delete few of the rows in my excel file with extension .xls . Excel version is 2007 . I know we can use xlrd xlwt  packages but I have no idea which are the function calls that need to be performed to delete rows or coloumns . I delete only those rows which contains a particular column with a specific file .

I know about `open_workbook` and reading rows and columns but is having trouble with deletion of a row in an Excel file .  At the same time I would also like to know if I can create a new excel file also and if so how ? A Document link on the above particular feature would be of great help but I could not find one which discusses about deletion of rows or colouns through python Script

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this website](http://www.python-excel.org/) here you'll have documentation,tutorials and etc for the xlrd xlwt packages and some others

Edit: From what i know you need to read the original file and copy what you need to a second file, discarding what you don't need